# Converting a curl POST request, to a curl JSON POST request

Tags: json, curl, post

I am using this curl line, in order to trigger a POST request to my server:

```
curl --data "item=my_item&is_done=true" 127.0.0.1:5000/convert
```

How can i convert the curl line, in order to send the same parameters, but through JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command

curl -d ‘{“item”: “my_item”, “is_done”: ”true”}’ -H “Content-Type: application/json” -x POST 127.0.0.1:5000/convert

Or

If you want to share parameters in file abcd.json then ,

curl -d “@abcd.json”  -H “Content-Type: application/json” -x POST 127.0.0.1:5000/convert

Comment: I actually used this:
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"item":"ZycugK6yXdHgf8foQTUnKY.txt","method":"my_method"}' 0.0.0.0:5000/convert

Comment: Why the IP address is 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 ?